# Xubuntu Terminal Cursor

Tags: command-line, 14.04, xubuntu, xfce4-terminal

I am running Xubuntu 14.04 and the default Terminal Emulator (xfterm I think).  The terminal itself is fine but I want to change the cursor to a blinking underline rather than a solid block.  How do I do this?  Can't see anything in the settings.

Comment: It would be great, if the cursor shape would change according to `overwrite-mode` of Bash shell.

Comment: The `overwrite-mode` is shell specific, but the cursor setting is application specific, so it seems to be impossible to have this, if you use several windows/tabs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the cursor shape in XFCE terminal by editing `${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-$HOME/.config}/xfce4/terminal/terminalrc` (expressed partly as [shell parameter expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02)), just find the `MiscCursorShape`variable and change it from `TERMINAL_CURSOR_SHAPE_BLOCK` to `TERMINAL_CURSOR_SHAPE_UNDERLINE`. In order to have a blinking cursor (any shape you defined) you must have `MiscCursorBlinks=TRUE` too.

System-wide defaults can be found under some of the colon separated directories `${XDG_CONFIG_DIRS:-/etc/xgd}`, respectively.

See [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) for more information about which directories are used and in which order.

For details and additional options on available in the graphical configuration tool, see http://docs.xfce.org/apps/terminal/advanced

Comment: This did not work for me, I have already tried it.  In my case I didn't even have a ~/.config/Terminal folder, never mind any file called terminalrc.  I tried creating it but it did not work.

Comment: Found it!  The file in question was in ~/.config/xfce4/terminal